# Mongoose is not able to pull id from array in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have got my schema like this

```
var PcardSchema = new Schema({

    Comments:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'commentSystem'
    }]

});
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Pcard', PcardSchema);

```
CommentSystem  Schema as
var commentSystem = new Schema({
    Questions: {
        type:String
    },
    Answer:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Pcard_AnswerSchema'

    }]
});

I am trying to achieve that whenever I deleted a Comment all its associated answer gets deleted and comment ID is also deleted from Comments array in PcardSchema 
So for that, i have created a pre middleware which is able to delete all the answer associated with that comment 


**Middleware**


commentSystem.pre('remove',function (next) {

    var CommentResults = this;
    async.each(CommentResults.Answer,function (id , callback) {
        console.log(id);
        Pcard_AnswerSchema.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err,ans) {

          if(err){
              callback("Please try Again later");  
          }else{
              callback();
          }
        })
    },function (err) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

});
```

At this point i am able to delete all the answer associated with this comment through this middleware but i am not able to pull that comment id from PcardSchema

```
async.waterfall([
                            function (callback) {
                                commentResults.remove();//deleting all asnwer
                                callback(null);
                            },
                            function (callback) {
                                commentSystem.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.QuesId,function (err , comm) {
                                    if(err){
                                       callback(err);
                                    }else{
                                        callback(null); //here i am deleting the comment and getting that comment id 
                                    }
                                })

                            },
                            function (callback) {
                                **Pcard.update({ _id: req.params.PcardId},
                                    {$pull:{'Comments': {'_id' : req.params.QuesID}}},function (err,rowaffected) {
                                        if(err){** //this area of code is not working
                                            callback(err);
                                        }else{
                                            callback(null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        ],
```

is it possible to pull the id from comment array in the pre middleware ?
any suggestion for improving the code ?

Comment: Because it's just `{ "$pull": { "Comments": req.params.QuesID } }`. With a "referenced" design it is simply an "array of ObjectId". You are confusing this with an "embedded document array", which has Document Objects with an `_id` field present in them. This is not what is defined in your schema.

Comment: So thankful to you for this.